# Determine bandwidth in GCP virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created machine in Google Cloud Platform A month ago
How do I know the cloud traffic bandwidth and number of hits of VM in Google Compute engine?

Comment: you can google it!;)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the individual VM's, theirs a monitoring tab that will show you network data up to a 30-day window.

If you want to view multiple VMs at once, you have two choices:

1. use Stackdriver via a monitoring application like Grafana or New Relic
2. export compute engine daily usage statistics (Compute Engine -> Settings) and parse them yourself or with another application (like Cloud Health)